# Octobercms Custom fields plugin for Rainlab.User show field in list

Tags: field, octobercms

please, know anybody how to show my custom filed from Custom Fields plugin for Rainlab.User plugin in list of users in Rainlab.User in backend?

For example i have custom field "valid_to" and I need it in the list of users without go to user detail.

thank you

Vaclav

Update:

Hi, thank you i tried extend the User plugin by Custom Fields ( https://octobercms.com/plugin/pkurg-customfields )

/plugins/pkurg/customfields/Plugin.php

On the list /rainlab/user/users the field valid_to is showed, but is empty .

When i clicked to sort "Valid To" alert window is opened:

"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'valid_to' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `users`.* from `users` order by `valid_to` desc limit 20 offset 0)" on line 664 of /www/doc/www.flexiqr.cz/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php

valid_to field is on the other table than users, is in pkurg_customfields_... right?

Thank you

Vaclav

Answer (score 0):

It's easy you can simply extend `UsersController` and add your `column` using `extendListColumns` function.

Ref : [How To Add New Column In October Cms List](https://tutorialmeta.com/octobercms/how-add-new-column-october-cms-list)

```php
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\SO;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;


use RainLab\User\Controllers\Users as UsersController;
use RainLab\User\Models\User;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function boot() {
        
        // extending Controller which has ListController Behavior 
        UsersController::extendListColumns(function($list, $model) {
        
            // we want only our User model be extended
            if (!$model instanceof User) {
                return;
            }
    
            // adding valid_to column
            $list->addColumns([
                'valid_to' => [
                    'label' => 'Valid To',
                    'type' => 'text', // or 'date'
                    'searchable' => true
                ]
            ]);
    
        });
    }
```

You will be able to see that column in the backend in `Rainlab.User record list`.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was add to question update with experience from plugin extend.
If you have any idea thank you for your feedback.